# android image picker, create thumbnails

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

There are images in device which doesn't have thumbnails (for example NFC transfered images)

Since I'm showing thumbnails in my image picker, this results in an error.

I could generate a bitmap from the original image and display it, but it is slow.

I see there's a concept of "media scan" where android scans images and generates thumbnails.

I tried to send "media scan" intent, but it doesn't seem to generate thumbnails as expected.
Besides it's another problem how I can show the generated thumbnail.

I tried to look for example code, but sample codes are rare for this matter.
Has anyone have tried/found code for this?

```
Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse(scanPath));
sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent); // doesn't actually generate thumbnails (I know because I run the app second times, thumbnails are not there, besides how do I get the generated thumbnail?
```

Comment: Have you checked that the folder is not a hidden folder and doesn't contain any .nomedia files ?. Thumbnail generation may fail in either cases